# Efficiently finding range of indices for positive values in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a large numpy array (typically of order 500,000x1024 but can be larger) and I'm trying to perform a couple of process that depend on where the positive values in the array are.
A very small example array might be

```
  [[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,-1.,-1., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 5., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 3., 1., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
   [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

The first is to replace any zeros between positive values that are less than three columns apart in each row. so if I replace these numbers with 50, my example output would be

```
 [[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,-1.,-1., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 1., 1.,50.,50., 1., 5., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 3., 1.,50.,50., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
```

The second thing I need to do is to write out some information for each row based on where the ranges of positive values are. For example using my altered array, I need to be able to write out one statement for the third row declaring positive integers for col[1:7] and two statements for the fourth row declaring positive integers in col[1:3] and col[6].

I've managed to utilise the numpy vectorised methods to a point to combat the first task, but have still ended up resorting to looping through both columns and rows (albeit on a subset of the whole array). Otherwise I end up replacing all of the zeros in a given row instead of just those between positive values.

But the second task I can't seem to find a way to do without cycling through the whole array using

```
for col in arr:
  for row in arr:
```

I guess my overall question would be, is there a way to make use of the vectorised methods in numpy to define column index ranges that will differ for each row and depend on the values in the following column?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy unfortunately can't do much processing without generating more arrays, so I fear any solution will require either some form of manual loop like you've been using, or creating one or more additional big arrays.  You may be able to come up with a solution that's quite fast and memory efficient using numexpr.

Here's a stab at doing this in a way that isn't necessarily memory efficient, but at least all the looping will be done by Numpy, so should be a lot faster than what you've been doing as long as it fits in your memory.  (Memory efficiency might be improved by rewriting some of this as in-place operations but I won't worry about that.)

Here's your step 1:

```
positive = x>0 # a boolean array marking the positive values in x

positive0 = positive[:,0:-3] # all but last 3 columns 
positive1 = positive[:,1:-2] # all but 1st and last 2 columns; not actually used
positive2 = positive[:,2:-1] # all but first 2 and last 1 columns
positive3 = positive[:,3:  ] # all but first 3 columns

# In the following, the suffix 1 indicates that we're viewing things from the perspective
# of entries in positive1 above.  So, e.g., has_pos_1_to_left1 will be True at
# any position where an entry in positive1 would be preceded by a positive entry in x

has_pos_1_to_left1 = positive0
has_pos_1_or_2_to_right1 = positive2 | positive3
flanked_by_positives1 = has_pos_1_to_left1 & has_pos_1_or_2_to_right1

zeros = (x == 0)       # indicates everywhere x is 0
zeros1 = zeros[:,1:-2] # all but 1st and last 2 columns

x1 = x[:,1:-2]         # all but 1st and last 2 columns

x1[zeros1 & flanked_by_positives1] = 50 # fill in zeros that were flanked - overwrites x!

# The preceding didn't address the next to last column, b/c we couldn't
# look two slots to the right of it without causing error.  Needs special treatment:
x[:,-2][ zeros[:,-2] & positive[:,-1] & (positive[:,-4] or positive[:,-3])] = 50
```

And here's your step 2:

```
filled_positives = x>0 # assuming we just filled in x
diffs = numpy.diff(filled_positives) # will be 1 at first positive in any sequence,
                                     # -1 after last positive, zero elsewhere

endings = numpy.where(diffs==-1) # tuple specifying coords where positive sequences end 
                                 # omits final column!!!
beginnings = numpy.where(diffs==1) # tuple specifying coords where pos seqs about to start
                                   # omits column #0!!!
```

It should be straightforward to use these beginning and ending coordinates to extract the information about each row you said you needed, but remember that this difference-detecting method only catches *transitions* from non-positive to positive, or vice versa, so it won't mention positive sequences beginning in the zeroth column or ending in the last column, so you'll need to look for those non-transitions separately if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use efficient numpy iterators like [flatiter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html#numpy.flatiter) or [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy.nditer)

For example, for your second task

```
In [1]: x = array([[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,-1.,-1., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 1., 1.,50.,50., 1., 5., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 3., 1.,50.,50., 2., 1., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
   ...:            [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

In [2]: islands = []
   ...: fl = x.flat
   ...: while fl.index < x.size:
   ...:     coord = fl.coords
   ...:     if fl.next() > 0:
   ...:         length = 1
   ...:         while fl.next() > 0:
   ...:             length +=1
   ...:         islands.append([coord, length])

In [3]: for (row, col), length in islands:
   ...:     print 'row:%d ; col[%d:%d]' %(row, col, col+length)
row:2 ; col[1:7]
row:3 ; col[1:3]
row:3 ; col[6:7]
row:4 ; col[1:7]
row:6 ; col[1:2]
row:6 ; col[5:7]
```

Answer (score -1):

**For your first problem:** create a variable that holds the index of the first positive number you come across and have an if statement that resets the position if the next value is positive and count (variable that counts position away from the first positive number) is less than 3.

**For your second problem:** Create an array and add the indices of the locations of positive values.

```
 String[] indices = new String[];
 int pos = 0;
 for col in arr:
     for row in arr:
        if(index is positive){
             indices[pos] = "[" + col + ":" + row + "]";
             pos++;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that still requires using for loops to cycle through every column and row which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid doing. My arrays are large and this takes a lot of time.                           I'm hoping there's a way I can do this using the built in functions that don't require looping through the array.

Comment: How are you creating the arrays? You could technically create an arraylist of objects containing the indices, the value, and whether or not it was positive. Then you could use a forloop to grab and return all the ones you want. The time of this solution would be O(N). Assuming youre not using an embedded forloop to create the arrays in the first place.

Comment: The array creation happens completely independently but they actually represent a sort of mask for the actual data that are held in a separate array of the same shape.

Comment: Various processes are run on the data and this 'mask' array is updated as a result. Once all that is done, it's passed to the process that will run the above operations. Would you have an example of how your suggestion would work? I'm not sure I can actually create the original arrays as you suggest though because of their relationship to the data. The data structure i.e. the 2D array is also representative of information about the data itself. It's frequency x time and when I write out the statements, it will include the frequencies and times needed.

Comment: The second method would have the data create objects so lets say you have a class:

Answer (score -1):

The second method would have the data create objects so lets say you have a class:

```
public class Matrix{
   int indicex;
   int indicey;
   double val;
   boolean positiveInt;

   //default constructor
   public Matrix(int indicex, int indicey, double val, boolean positiveInt){
   this.indicex = indicex;
   this.indicey = indicey;
   this.val = val;
   this.positiveInt = positiveInt;
   }    

   //getter
   public boolean isPositive(){
        if(positiveInt == true){
              return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

and then in your driver class you would have have your data being read and create an object new Matrix(indexx, indexy, val, true/false)....and that would be put into an arraylist that you could search on for positive numbers.

```
List<Matrix> storeObjects = new ArrayList<Matrix>();
some method(){
   Matrix matrixObject = new Matrix(indexx, indexy, val, trueOrFalse);
   storeObjects.add(matrixObject)
 }

 for every object in store objects 
    if(object.isPositive()){
         put object in a separate array of positive objects
     }
  }
```

Comment: That makes sense, it would still take quite a bit of manipulation of the final array to get back out what columns on each row (i.e. what frequencies at each time) I need to write in my final statement. My main query with that suggestion though is as I can't create this matrix with the initial data arrays, as far as I can tell I'd still end up having to do an element-wise loop through my whole array to interpret it into the matrix list first?